# how to solve this union problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that

$A = \{ \{m\}, \{x\}\}$

$B = \{ \{d\} ,\{s\}\}$

What is $A\cup B$?

Is it $\{ \{ m,d\}, \{m,s\}, \{x,d\}, \{x,s\}\}$ or
$\{\{M\}, \{x\}, \{d\}, \{s\}\}$?

Comment: The second answer is correct, if $M$ is replaced by $m$. The union operation simply collects all the elements contained in either set.

Comment: Do you understand the definition of $X\cup Y$? Did you try to apply it to this case?

Comment: If you add {.} around each letter in your first proposition, you get the cartesian product which has nothing to do with the union.

Answer (score 4):

If we let $a_1=\{m\}$ and $a_2=\{x\}$, and we let $b_1=\{d\}$ and $b_2=\{s\}$, then we have $$A=\{a_1,a_2\}$$ and $$B=\{b_1,b_2\}.$$

By definition,
\begin{align*}
A \cup B &= \{x: x \in A \text{ or } x \in B\} \\
 &= \{a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\} \\
 &= \{\{m\},\{x\},\{d\},\{s\}\}.
\end{align*}

(The initial substitution isn't necessary; it's to help prevent getting confused about "sets of sets".)

Answer (score 0):

The second option is correct:
$$\{\{m\},\{x\},\{d\},\{s\}\}$$